# In angular cli how can you add meta data to routes e.g. title and description tags

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, reflect-metadata

In angular cli how can you add meta data to routes e.g. title and description tags?

**These are my routes:**

```
import { Route} from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

export const HomeRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

I want to add title and description to these routes so that they are seen in the browser e.g. title for each route.

Furthermore, I would like them to be picked up by bots e.g. google seo bots.

**I'm using angular cli with webpack, angular version 4, and typescript.**

**Current Error:**

[image]

Comment: Route has a `data` property on it. It may be worth looking into. It is defined as: *data is additional data provided to the component via ActivatedRoute*. Whatever that means. :) Not finding a good example on angular.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a npm module ng2-metadata [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-metadata]
it will serve the need.

Sample Code.

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      metadata: {
        title: 'Sweet home',
        description: 'Home, home sweet home... and what?'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'duck',
    component: DuckComponent,
    data: {
      metadata: {
        title: 'Rubber duckie',
        description: 'Have you seen my rubber duckie?'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'toothpaste',
    component: ToothpasteComponent,
    data: {
      metadata: {
        title: 'Toothpaste',
        override: true, // prevents appending/prepending the application name to the title attribute
        description: 'Eating toothpaste is considered to be too healthy!'
      }
    }
  }
  ...
];
```

Add this in app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    MetadataModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

And inject it in component constructor.

```
  constructor(private metadataService: MetadataService) { }
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the link I need to add to the angular cli Json file for it?

Comment: the link is mentioned in answer, include this js  `node_modules/ng2-metadata/bundles/ng2-metadata.umd.min.js`
in angular-cli.json

Comment: I've added that link: node_modules/ng2-metadata/bundles/ng2-metadata.umd.min.js to the scripts section of the angular-cli.json. But when I do this bash command: "ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=none" I get this error: "Error in multi script loader"

Comment: It only works when I do an ng serve and not a ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=none I've attached the screen shot above now

Comment: just out of curiosity what happens when u remove line in angular cli.json & generate the build

Comment: It just started working now. Strange. Only issue I have is when you try to change route you get a 404

Comment: in route you will define exact route right .? so /home won't work in route file. You can accept it as answer if it helped

Comment: Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-metadata
there is function defined for AOT compilation.

Comment: Thanks il give that a go

Comment: Let me know if it works, i will edit the answer. or you can create some GIT, i can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As the author **`ng2-metadata`** and **`@ngx-meta/core`** projects, I'd suggest you to have a look at the package description (**README** file), as **README** files contain up-to-date information in most cases.

There's a **depreciation warning** on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-metadata) of **`ng2-metadata`**,  saying that the project is deprecated, no longer maintained and now continues at [**`@ngx-meta/core`**](https://github.com/ngx-meta/core).

If you switch using **`@ngx-meta/core`**, you'll notice that the current issues you described here have already been resolved.

About **`@ngx-meta/core`**: **`@ngx-meta/core`** is the successor of **`ng2-metadata`**, and the actual releases are **`v0.4.x`** and **`v0.2.x`**.

> If you're using `@angular v4.x.x`, use the latest release of `v0.4.x` (*[master] branch*).

The latest release for Angular 4 is `v0.4.0-rc.1` as of now.

> If you're using `@angular v2.x.x`, use the latest release of `v0.2.x` (*[v0.2.x] branch*).

The latest release for Angular 2 is `v0.2.0-rc.5` as of now.